# How to have multiple voice triggers for one IntentService/Service?

Tags: android-intent, android-service, google-glass, google-gdk

Right now i have 1 voice trigger for my IntentService.

My manifest looks like this:

```
 <service android:name="HelloIntentService" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
            android:resource="@xml/hello_show" />
    </service>
```

My hello show looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger keyword="@string/show_helloworld_voice_trigger"/>
```

I would like to start my service with more than 1 voice trigger and then to be able to find out which voice trigger started it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create multiple "dummy" activities, each with its own voice trigger. Each of them will call your "real" activity with some intent extra indicating which trigger was used.

Comment: OK, i thought of that but dismissed it as complicating thigs. If there is not other way, i will do it this way.